# copy a part of a text line from a text document into a new document

Tags: python

I have a bunch of URL's in a text file but I'm only interested in one part of the URL and I want to save that part into another document. I've maneged to read 1 line at a time and then writing it to a file using this:

```
from sys import argv
script, sol , save = argv

data = open(sol)
indata = data.read()


result = indata[51:85]   
result2 = "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/00003/mcam/" + result + ".jpg"

output = open(save, 'w')
output.write(result2)

data.close()
output.close()
```

But I'm unable to port that into a for loop:

```
from sys import argv
script, sol = argv

data = open(sol)
indata = data.read()

for line in indata:
   indata[51:85],


data.close()
```

I tried to print it in the screen to see why am getting it wrong but I only get empy lines. I'm stuck and I hope you can give me a hand.

```
from sys import argv
script, sol, save = argv

data = open(sol)
indata = data.read()

def get_line():
    for line in indata.splitlines():
        print indata[51:85]

        result = indata[51:85]
        result2 = "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/00003/mcam/" + result + ".jpg"

    output = open(save, 'w')
    output.write(result2)
    output.close()

get_line()    
data.close()
```

I've managed to do this but I can only save the first line in the new document. The rest are printed on the screen but not saved in the new document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Your control flow is off. You need to open the file before the loop

the `result=...` line is probably a bit confusing so I'll explain it

first it uses `.replace` to change text in the line.  Then it uses indexing `[:-4]` to drop the last 4 characters.  Finally it appends the string '-br.jpg' to the whole thing

```
from sys import argv
script, sol, save = argv

def get_line():
    data = open(sol)
    output = open(save, 'w')
    for line in data: #for each line in the input file
        result = line.replace('msl/multimedia/raw/?rawid=', 'msl-raw-images/msss/00003/mcam/')[:-4] + '-br.jpg\n'
        output.write(result)

    output.close()
    data.close()

get_line()
```

---

you can iterate the lines of the file itself

```
from sys import argv
script, sol = argv

data = open(sol)
for line in data:
   print line[51:85]

data.close()
```

seems closer to what you want.

When you do `.read()` you're grabbing the contents of the entire file as a single string.  then you're indexing characters in that **entire** string, not a specific line.  In the above code, you're indexing into each line one at a time.

Also, since this is a url and you're only interested in one section, the `.split` method could make your indexing easier.  It returns a list of strings made by splitting your original string at a specific character.  for example:

```
>>> line = 'stackoverflow.com/posts/11908027/'
>>> line.split('/')
['stackoverflow.com', 'posts', '11908027', '']
>>> line.split('/')[2]
'11908027'
>>> line.split('/')[1]
'posts'
```

Comment: I tried your code as is here and I'm getting the same. Do I have to create another loop that executes this one? For example if I have five URL's do I have to create another foor lop that executes this one five times?

Comment: @marclluell no this should read all five lines and do what you want.  Could you post the contents of one of these input files?

Comment: Now I'm also getting a global error because indata is not defined

Comment: @marclluell my mistake, that last indata should have been `line`

Comment: Now it works fine except that the .jpg is written a line below the rest of the URL except for the last line. I supose that's something related to the escape sequence but I tried to change it's position but it hasn't worked.

Comment: And sorry to be so small headed

Comment: @marclluell show me one line from the input file and I can probably fix that.  or you can try `result = line[51:85].rstrip()` to remove trailing whitespace

Comment: all the input lines are the same structure and lenght it only changes one or two numbers

Comment: @marclluell I changed the `result=` line.  this should do what you want

Comment: @xhainingx: I think you should use the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) when working with files, otherwise your answer seems good so far.

Comment: Thank you very much, the last line ends diffent than the others but don't worry I can fix it manually as it's only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for line in indata.splitlines():
    print indata[51:85]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into "split" and "splitline", which are useful when breaking up standard text, such as url. You can learn more about each here:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

That list will also have some info on partitions() which may be of use to you as well. It takes a string and separator, given you a few options on how to store the data.